# Play framework template for cycle

Tags: scala, templates, playframework

I'm trying to print some html elements in a for cycle in a template.

Template:

```
    <ul>
     @for(index <- 0 until appointments.size){
    <li>
        @(utils.DateUtil.getDate(appointments(index).getStartDate())) - @appointments(index).getReason()
        <ul>

            @{val procedure = appointments(index).getProcedures()

                if(procedure.size() == 0)
                {
                    <b>žádna procedura nebyla vykonána</b>
                }
                else 
                {
                    <b>test</b>

                    for(proc <- procedure)
                    {
                    <b>for test</b>
                    }
                }

            }


        </ul>

    </li>
    }

</ul>
```

The problem lies in the `else` branch.

if I remove this code:

```
 for(proc <- procedure)
 {
  <b>for test</b>
 }
```

It prints out **test**

But if I leave it there nothing from the `else` branch prints out

I've tried encapsulating the code in curly braces, a different for cycle notation -> `for(index2 <- 0 until procedure.size)` but nothing worked.

Comment: I suggested you using `defining` instead `@{val procedure...` last time -> remember ?

Comment: I'll give it a shot later today

Comment: Ok, it worked like a charm, If you'll post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: What is type of your `appointments` variable? (it is passed from controller, right?)

Comment: appointment is a List passed from the controller, it contains some primitive data and another collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that's a templating engine, although it's Scala based, some things just doesn't work - ie. variables declaration (as by definition it's job of controller). Play has a replacement for that (if really required) as:

```
@defining(appointments(index).getProcedures()) { procedure => 
   <b>Common HTML using defined @procedure</b>
}
```

Anyway if I'm not wrong, properly your code written in Play's template should look like below.

```
@(appointments: List[Appointment])

<ul>
    @for(appointment <- appointments) {
        <li>
            @(utils.DateUtil.getDate(appointment.getStartDate())) - @appointment.getReason()
            @if(appointment.getProcedures() != null && appointment.getProcedures().size()>0) {
                <ul>
                    @for(procedure <- appointment.getProcedures()){
                         <li>@Messages("procedure.execuded") @procedure.name</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            } else {
                <b>@Messages("no.execuded.procedures")</b>
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

*Note: written from finger, it CAN contain errors*

Comment: the whole template included the "imports" from controller, I've put here just the problematic part, i wanted to define a variable because I have a collection inside another collection, so I wanted to call my code this way `_var_.getSomething()` where `_var_` is the inner collection, instead of `collection1.get(i).getCollection2().get(i)` , nevertheless you helped me, dziękuję bardzo

Answer (score 0):

**@**for(proc <- procedure)
 {
  **for test**
 }

It is also considered a bad practice to define variables inside the view. The right way is to pass all the collections/data-classes from action and just iterate them in the view.

Comment: what if I'm passing a collection that contains another collection?

Comment: `@for(proc <- procedure) { for test }` gives me `identifier expected but 'for' found.` the error is on right after @ symbol, if I encapsulate the `for` cycle in `{` `}` it compiles, but again, no output